# Swapping views in a tab bar app calling the view controller directly and not by its index

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to swap views in a tab bar application but I can't rely on the index of the view controllers as they change. So I cannot use the code below:

```
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:4];
```

I want to be able to call a specific view controller by name. How can I do this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select view controller of a specific class using this code:

```
NSUInteger index = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                    return [obj isKindOfClass:[ClassOfViewControllerYouAreLookingFor class]];
            }];
if(index != NSNotFound) {
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index];
}
```

Or you can simply select a specific ViewController instance using this code:

```
NSUInteger index = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:yourViewController];
if(index != NSNotFound) {
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index];
 }
```

Comment: What if they are the same class? You should really be using `self.tabBarController.viewControllers[someIndex]`